# Elongation of a rotating string with mass attached to it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram, string

How can we calculate the elongation of a rotating string with a mass attached to it? We know, that the mass has a velocity of v and the other end of the string is fixed. Gravity is normal earth gravity and the rotation is perpendicular with the earth surface.

Answer (score 0):

Use centripetal force equation (to find tension). Then, use the equation for Young's modulus. Recall that Young's modulus is$$\mathcal Y = \dfrac{F_\perp}{A}\dfrac{l_0}{\Delta l}$$